# Magento2: Checkout Suite from IWD

Tags: magento2, checkout

I wanted to install the free version of this extension and test it.
But I saw that there is only one language version for the free version.
Does anyone know how I can create a file for my language and translate this module?

https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html